# Was this major character a Slan?

Tags: slan

In A.E. van Vogt’s (1940) classic science fiction novel *Slan*, there are mutant humans named slan hiding amongst humans. Some of them are revealed in the novel but is

> John Petty — the head of secret police — one of them? He seems to have an extraordinary capacity to hide his mind, much like the other tendrilless slan.

Could he have been a hidden slan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Everything indicates that Petty was just naturally very good at keeping his thoughts well guarded.  Even if he did not know he was doing so, having that kind of shielding might turn out to be a useful skill for someone whose career was dedicated to fighting against the slan.

When Jommy Cross first hitches a ride on Petty's car, he encounters the police chief's mental shield and concludes that, while it is quite effective, that does not mean he is a slan.

> It wasn’t, Jommy thought, amazed, as if John Petty could be consciously guarding his thoughts.  But there was a shield here as effective in hiding true thoughts as any slan’s.  Yet it wasdifferent.  Overtones came through that told of a remorseless character, a highly trained and brilliant brain.  Suddenly there was the tail end of a thought, brought to the surface by a flurry of passion that shattered the man’s calm:  ‘I—I’ve got to kill that slan girl, Kathleen Layton.  That’s the only way to undermine Kier Gray—‘

Much later, when Cross encounters the shield put up by a true slan, the dictator Kier Gray, the shield is quite different.

> It was the words that did it.  For with them came surface thoughts, and those surface thoughts were a deliberate screen held over a mind shield as tight as his own.  No leaky tendrilless slan shield this, but an enormous fact.

At this point, very near the end of the book, Jommy has gotten extremely adept at studying the minds of all three types of humans (normals, true slan, and tendrilless slan) and distinguishing among them.  Jommy's internal monologue specifically contrasts Gray's more sophisticated shield with the shield protecting Petty's mind, which he explicitly confirms was human.

> All those years that Kathleen Layton had lived with Kier Gray, and not suspected the truth.  Of course she had lacked experience with mind shields, and there had been John Petty with a similar type of shield to confuse the issue, **because John Petty was human**. How cleverly the dictator had imitated the human way of thought protection!